# How to paste into merged cells with phonetic

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet1.Range("C7").Value = Sheet1.Range("C2").Value
→ I can't keep a phonetics with this form.

So I use to paste using a PasteSpecial, xlPasteValues
But its Error: all the merged cells need to be the same size
How can I just paste only value.

```
Sub test()
    Sheet1.Range("C2").Copy
    Sheet1.Range("C7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  ' Error ! 

   ' Sheet1.Range("C7").Value = Sheet1.Range("C2").Value
   ' I can't use this, This is can't keep a phonetics.

End Sub
```

C7:G7 Cell must retain its existing format.
Merged cells cannot be unpacked.
Is there a way to bypass or ignore errors?

[image: Detail Example Picture]

Comment: I'm added an example photo. Thank you.

Comment: Does it mean that phonetics is included in the format, so it can't be transported separately?

Comment: Select C2, you can check its `real` value on formula box.